# How to set div innerHTML in web Components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

html code:

```
<div id="scks" is="select-checkbox" url="data.json" displayName="name" displayValue="value">
</div>
```

js Code:

```
// i want to set html to div(#scks)
// it dose not work
// this is the div(#scks)
select_checkbox_proto.createdCallback = function(){
    that.setValue("afterEnd");
}
select_checkbox_proto.setValue = function(val){
    this.innerHTML = val;
}


document.registerElement("select-checkbox",{prototype:select_checkbox_proto,extends: 'div'});
```

Any one can help me?

1: this is the current div(#scks)?
2: how to set value to div.

Comment: @Supersharp   i mean this == scks return true, in the createdCallback I want to give this div an initialization value, and this div will show us in the page.  But the code can not work.

Comment: this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute( "displayValue" )

Answer (score -1):

your question is not clear for me. if you want to put custom html into div you can use.

```
$("#scks").html("your custom html");
```

and if you want to change attribute for some element you can use attr() or prop()

```
$("#scks").prop('NewAttr', 'NewValue');
```

Comment: code:
1:select_checkbox_proto.createdCallback = function(){
    this.setValue("afterEnd");
}
this == $("#scks").get(0)   --->true  (it can work)

2: $(this).html("something")    it can not work   Why and how to fix it

Comment: we can not use $("#scks").html("your custom html");  in the js code.